# how to update a field according to first entry of a user?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table name devices.

```
+---------+---------------+---------------------+
| user_id | device_status | created_at          |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+
|       1 |             0 | 2017-03-10 10:39:41 |
|       1 |             0 | 2017-03-14 10:19:33 |
|       2 |             0 | 2017-03-14 10:57:59 |
|       1 |             0 | 2017-03-15 05:58:51 |
|       3 |             0 | 2017-03-15 06:01:32 |
|       3 |             0 | 2017-03-15 12:10:13 |
+---------+---------------+---------------------+
```

What i want to do is update `device_status` of a user_id which have stored first in mysql table.

for example we have 3 rows of user_id 1. with created_at date. i want to update device_status of user_id 1 created_at date 2017-03-10 10:39:41.

EDIT 1: the query i use

```
UPDATE devices 
   SET device_status = 1 
 WHERE created_at = (SELECT created_at 
                       FROM (SELECT MIN(created_at) AS created_at 
                               FROM devices) AS t);
```

but this query only updated one record (2017-03-10 10:39:41).
i want to update

```
|       2 |             0 | 2017-03-14 10:57:59 |
```

and

```
|       3 |             0 | 2017-03-15 06:01:32 |
```

records too.

Comment: Have you tried using min(created_at)?? What issues are you facing?

Comment: the issue is how to check user_id?

Comment: Do you want to do batch update or single row update for every time?

Comment: post the `SQL` you tried

Comment: @HakanSONMEZ batch update.

Comment: @RealCheeseLord wait let me edit post.

Comment: @RealCheeseLord i updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you Dates are mutually exclusive you could just Group by user_id:

```
UPDATE devices 
   SET device_status = 1 
 WHERE created_at IN (SELECT created_at 
                        FROM (SELECT MIN(created_at) AS created_at 
                                FROM devices
                               GROUP BY user_id) AS t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use min() function in subquery with where clause.

```
update devices set device_status=1 where user_id = 1 and 
created_at = (select min(created_at)  where user_id = 1);
```

Hope it solves your problem.